Expo-camera does not recognize qr codes on web but on android
I am trying to read QR codes with react web. I cannot read qr codes from web but on Android I can. No errors appears con web console, but qr codes are not detected.
This is the code in App.tsx
import { CameraView, CameraType, useCameraPermissions, BarcodeScanningResult } from 'expo-camera';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const [facing, setFacing] = useState<CameraType>('back');
  const [permission, requestPermission] = useCameraPermissions();
  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
  const [scanned, setScanned] = useState(false);

  if (!permission) {
    return <View />;
  }

  if (!permission.granted) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.message}>We need your permission to show the camera</Text>
        <Button onPress={requestPermission} title="grant permission" />
      </View>
    );
  }

  const handleBarCodeScanned = (result: BarcodeScanningResult) => {
 
    if (result) {
      const { type, data } = result;
        console.log(data);
        alert(data);
    }
  };



  return (
               <View style={styles.container}>
                <CameraView
                  facing="back"
                   // @ts-ignore - The type is not recognized; it is a bug. On the Web, it does not work properly if this type is missing.
                  type="back"
                    barcodeScannerSettings={{
                        barcodeTypes: [
                            'aztec',
                            'ean13',
                            'ean8',
                            'qr',
                            'pdf417',
                            'upc_e',
                            'datamatrix',
                            'code39',
                            'code93',
                            'itf14',
                            'codabar',
                            'code128',
                            'upc_a',
                        ],
                    }}
                    onBarcodeScanned={handleBarCodeScanned}
                    style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}
                />
                {scanned && (
                    <Button
                        title={'Tap to Scan Again'}
                        onPress={() => setScanned(false)}
                    />
                )}
            </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  message: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    paddingBottom: 10,
  },
  camera: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    margin: 64,
  },
  button: {
    flex: 1,
    alignSelf: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: 'white',
  },
});

This is my package.json
{
  "name": "expo-camera-5",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/metro-runtime": "~3.2.3",
    "expo": "~51.0.28",
    "expo-camera": "~15.0.15",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.5",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.45",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
  "private": true
}


Another issue that I had was with selecting back camera, but this problem was passed
No codes are detected
I try using
"expo": "50.0.18"
but I have the same results
